# Register a Gallio zip installation with TestDriven.Net

Tags: mbunit, gallio, testdriven.net

I want to register a copy of the Gallio zip installation with TestDriven.Net.  In another thread, a member has mentioned that the Gallio installer needs to run after the TD installer in order to register Gallio with TD.  Unfortunately, I can't run the lastest Gallio installer per corporate policy.  Is there a way around this problem?  Thanks.

Update: Manually editing the registry worked for me.

On Windows XP, under HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/MutantDesign/TestDriven.NET/TestRunners,
Add key Gallio.

Under Gallio, add

1. AssemblyPath - /bin/TDNet/Gallio.TDNetRunner.dll
2. TypeName - Gallio.TDNetRunner.GallioTestRunner
3. TypeName_Resident - Gallio.TDNetRunner.GallioResidentTestRunner

Then change

1. (Default) - 25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use Gallio.Utility to install the td.net plugin:

http://www.gallio.org/wiki/doku.php?id=tools:setup_utility_command

Comment: Ah, sorry, should have read that more carefully. In theory, you could perform the required steps manually, but you probably won't have the authoritar to do that either (registry settings etc). Which means you're out of luck :(

Comment: if you can point me to the list of manual steps, I can give them a try.  I don't have an issue editing the registry.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/mb-unit/source/browse/trunk/v3/src/Extensions/TDNet/Gallio.TDNetRunner/Core/TDNetRunnerInstaller.cs

Comment: I experience a problem outputting log messages to the console window.  Does it have anything to do with the way Gallio is registered with TestDriven.NET?  Any ideas are welcomed.  I didn't find this issue with NUnit+TestDriven.