# Unable to output log messages in MbUnit + TestDriven

Tags: mbunit, gallio, testdriven.net

I am unable to to output log messages to console via the Common.Logging framework in MbUnit tests run by TestDriven.  I am not sure if it has to do with the way Gallio is registered with TestDriven.  I followed the steps on this post ( [Register a Gallio zip installation with TestDriven.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023667/register-a-gallio-zip-installation-with-testdriven-net) ) to register Gallio with TestDriven manually because I don't have admin rights to the machine.

The same logging mechanism worked in NUnit + TestDriven.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really want to write messages to the Output pane in Visual Studio when running TestDriven.NET you can use `Gallio.Framework.DiagnosticLog`:

```cs
DiagnosticLog.WriteLine("Test message");
```

However, the log messages won't be associated to the tests and will show up as a separate section of the Gallio report.  So in most cases you're better off using the `Gallio.Framework.TestLog` or `System.Console` and clicking on the Test Report link to see the results as Graham mentioned.

Comment: I am aware of DiagnosticLog.  It would be nice if Gallio can channel log messages to the Output pane just like NUnit.

Answer (score 0):

Console output goes into the test report (the blue link at the end of the TD.NET run), rather than being displayed in the console. Is there anything in there?