# Cannot write to gallio.echo console using NativeConsole.Instance in 64 bit OS

Tags: unit-testing, 64-bit, mbunit, gallio

With Windows 7 32-bit I was able to output text to Gallio.Echo runner using Gallio.Runtime.ConsoleSupport.NativeConsole.Instance.WriteLine(""). But I'm failed with it in Windows 7 64-bit. Is there any way to accomplish it? I'm using Gallio bundle 3.4.14.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
Gallio.Framework.DiagnosticLog.WriteLine("message");
```

I have not tested in Windows 7, just in Vista.

You might find the following answer useful as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9775222/13441